# How to I have a value increase every loop in lua?

Tags: lua

How do I have increasing increments during a loop? Ex;

```
a = "1"
for i = 10, 1,-1
do 
    print(a .. " test")
end
```

So how would I make it to where each of the 10 for loops, it prints out;
1 test, 
4 test, 
7 test, 
10 test, 
13 test, 
16 test, 
19 test, 
22 test, 
25 test, 
28 test,

Comment: Anyone? Please :/

Comment: please refer to the Lua manual for questions regarding the very basics of the language

Answer (score 0):

```
for i = 1, 28, 3 do
  print(i .. " test")
end
```

`i` starts at `1` and is increased by `3` in every cycle until it reaches `28`

Refer to [Lua Manual 3.3.5 For-Statement](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5)

> ```
> for v = e1, e2, e3 do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>  do
>    local var, limit, step = tonumber(e1), tonumber(e2), tonumber(e3)
>    if not (var and limit and step) then error() end
>    var = var - step
>    while true do
>      var = var + step
>      if (step >= 0 and var > limit) or (step < 0 and var < limit) then
>        break
>      end
>      local v = var
>      block
>    end
>  end
> ```